# Omnet++ simulation stopped at setting up qtenv and loading images

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I am using Omnet++ since a while, but this time I face a strange error.
My simulation works properly until suddenly without I make any changes in the code the simulation starts hanging at "Setting up Qtenv" when loading images from the images path. I tried everything even uninstalling Avira antivirus but still the problem not solved.

The following images are related to the issue:
1- this image is when the simulation starts:
[image]

2- this image remains like this forever until I kill the process:
[image]

3- and this image I found in the progress tab
[image]

I thought that the problem is in the java runtime error but I am not sure. So, I made a small change in the environment variables. I just changed the forward slash to the backward slash as shown in the image bellow.
[image]

still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `.qtenvrc` from the main directory of your project.

Comment: I did remove the .qtenvrc but unfortunately not succeeded

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a `.qtenvrc` one in the main directory of the project and the other in the administrator main directory (e.g. in windows c:\users\huawei ). I removed them all. Thank you @Jerzy D  for your hint.

[image: Illustration]